# Delete XML child node

Tags: xml, dom, xpath

hi i am having trouble in deleting XML node.

```
    <Instance>
      <Internal>
        <Attribute>
        <Name>length</Name>
        </Attribute>
      <Name>internal</Name>
      </Internal>
    <Name>Instanec</Name>
   </Instance>
```

i want to delete Name Node so that my output is below.

```
    <Instance>
      <Internal>
        <Attribute>
        </Attribute>
      </Internal>
   </Instance>
```

i tried the following code :

```
NodeList baseElmntLst2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("Name");
        for (int k = 0; k < baseElmntLst2.getLength(); k++) {
            Element node = (Element) baseElmntLst2.item(k);
            Element node2 = (Element) baseElmntLst2.item(k).getParentNode();
            node2.removeChild(node);
```

}

but it does not delete all Name Elements which i dont understand.

Thankyou

Comment: What lang are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM `NodeList`s are [live collections](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#td-live) so if you want to delete all items in a `NodeList` one way is to start at the end e.g. `for (int k = baseElmntLst2.getLength(); k >= 0; k--)`. Or use `while (baseElmntLst2.getLength() > 0) baseElmntLst2.item(0).getParentNode().removeChild(baseElmntLst2.item(0));`.